# batch file that updates to user input revision number using tortoise svn

Tags: batch-file, version-control, tortoisesvn

I was wondering if I could make a batch script where the user enters what version of software they would want to run, and then through tortoise svn, the software would "update to revision" and run that user entered version. 
 I'm really new to writing batch files but this is what I have so far.... it's kind of a mash-up between a bunch of things I found online so it probably doesn't make any sense. please help :'(

```
@echo off
echo.
echo. [ SVN Version Control ]
pause
set SOURCE=C:\Users\bradyka1\Desktop\software
set /p Version=Enter The Version Number: %=%
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
echo.
echo. Updating %SOURCE% to SVN...
"%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:revision: "%Version%" /path /closeonend:2
echo. done.
```

Answer (score 1):

Rea-read [TortoiseProc description and commands](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html), fix obvious delirium (but **The Right Way (tm)** is to use for automation always pure CLI-interface)

Dirty draft (**TBT!**)

```
"%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update  /rev:%Version% /path:"%SOURCE%" /closeonend:2
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops - should have read the documentation more thoroughly. You can leave out the user input and have teh SVN GUI pop-up instead and have the user enter that there.

```
set /p Version=Enter The Version Number: %=%
CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\www\Users\bradyka1\Desktop\software1\" /rev:%Version% /closeonend:0
```